# Simply restricting an Eclipse RCP application to only run in English

Tags: java, eclipse, internationalization, rcp

I got a fairly simple question, but I cannot find anything that helps.

I am building an Eclipse RCP application which does NOT have to be localized in different languages. In fact: I want it to just offer an English UI.

So, all my views, editors, menus are nicely only displayed in English the way I want it.

BUT: I use property views and other stuff coming from given Eclipse plugins - and all of them are using my system's language (which is German). My UI now looks totally awkward with mixed languages that I simply don't want.

So, my question is not how to properly internationalize an application, but rather NOT to have it display anything but English, no matter what the system is it's running on.

Should be, easy, shouldn't it?

I tried setting default locale with this:

```
Locale.setDefault(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

in the Application class start method, but that does not help at all. Why? Where does it get the language from?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

you can look at following runtime options to configure eclipse platform.

http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fruntime-options.html

**osgi.nl** is an option to run platform with desired locale.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your `.product` file in the *launching* tab. In the '*launching arguments*' part put in the '*All platforms tab*' :

```
-nl en
```

Don't forget to export the product before testing. If you want to launch your app using Eclipse, put the previous line to your '*Run configuration*' in the '*Arguments*' tab